# Gradle publish to artifactory - Could not find method artifactoryPublish()

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, artifactory

I'm trying to publish an artifact to artifactory using gradle, however gradle doesn't recognize artifactoryPublish() or artifactory(). I receive the following error:

```
Could not find method artifactoryPublish() for arguments [build_9ujhxzionc580et0ezlx54vcs$_run_closure4@14af6c29] on root project 'uw-data-util' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

My gradle version 3.5

Here is my **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "maven"
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://artifactory.internal.com/artifactory/libs-release/"
        credentials { username = project.hasProperty('artifactory_user') ? project.artifactory_user : System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_USER']
            password = project.hasProperty('artifactory_password') ? project.artifactory_password : System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_KEY']}
    }
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
    //compile group: 'com.monitorjbl', name: 'xlsx-streamer', version: '1.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.1.1'
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3'
    compile group: 'postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
    compile group:  'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.8.7'
    compile group:  'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.1'
    compile "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.4.17"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

artifactoryPublish {
        publications(publishing.publications.mavenJava)
    }

artifactory {
    contextUrl = "https://artifactory.internal.com/artifactory/libs-release-local/"
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "libs-release-local"
            username = project.hasProperty('artifactory_user') ? project.artifactory_user : System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_USER']
            password = project.hasProperty('artifactory_password') ? project.artifactory_password : System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_KEY']
        }
        defaults {
            publications('mavenJava')
            publishArtifacts = true
        }
    }
    resolve {
        repoKey = 'libs-release-local'
    }
}

jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": "com.internal.qa.automation.file.util.DbRunUtil" )
    }
}

group = 'com.internal'
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.version = '1.0'
        pom.artifactId = 'uw-data-util'
        pom.packaging = 'jar'
    }
}

test {
    def suiteXml = System.getProperty("SUITE")
    systemProperty "ENV_NAME", System.getProperty("ENV_NAME")
    useTestNG {
        if(suiteXml == "profile-smoke"){
            suites "src/test/resources/testng/groups/smoke/${suiteXml}.xml"
        }
        testLogging {
            showStandardStreams = true
            exceptionFormat "full"
            events "started", "passed", "skipped", "failed", "standardOut", "standardError"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm apparently missing something from the documentation.

Comment: You don't seem to have applied any plugin that would add these methods.

Comment: good eye. after adding `apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory`, I get `Plugin with id 'com.jfrog.artifactory' not found.`

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/rtf/gradle+artifactory+plugin

Comment: That's the page I am referring too

Comment: So, what are the two different ways of applying the plugin? Which one did you use? None of them consists in just adding `apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"` to your script.

Comment: @S.D you need to add classpath to your buildscript dependencies as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was:

```
plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.4.18"
}

.....
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
```

since I was using gradle version 2.1+

Answer (score 6):

I solved this add one more plugin:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'

    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.16.1"
}

apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

I use gradle 6.2

Comment: for future readers, gradle-6.7-all.zip for me and this worked.  namely, i added "apply plugin: 'maven-publish'" right next to my apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following plugin in `build.gradle` solved it for me

`apply plugin: 'maven-publish'`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the older gradle approach:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
  }
}

...

apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just so you're aware, it's always best to include as much background and explanation so that the author and future readers who may not be as experienced know why and how it works.

Comment: @DanielBickler The example is self-explanatory. It is the same one provided in the official Artifactory documentation. Being one of the people you say it will benefit to provide (excessive) background and explanation, I disagree.